# How to change the title of a paper without harming the citation counts

Tags: citations, google-scholar, tools

Sometimes, after I publish a working paper in arXiv or a refereed paper in a conference, I change the title of the paper. This can be due to several reasons:

- A reviewer in a journal I submitted to suggested a better title;
- I found out a different paper with a similar title and decided to change my own paper's title to prevent confusion;
- I submitted to a double-blind venue and wanted to reduce the chances that the reviewers find my working paper.

My concern is that this title-change might confuse search engines such as Google Scholar. Nowadays, automatic citation counts are counted towards promotion so this consideration should be taken into account.

My question is: how can I change the title of a paper, in a way that will not harm its automatic citation counts?

Comment: Google Scholar allows you to merge two papers, if you don't mind having to make a manual intervention